# In Woo comerce show second category ( not primary ) if there is no second category, then show primary

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, categories

I'm looking to show second listed category if one exists, if not, then I want to show the first ( primary category )
Here is what I have so far:

```
    <?php $categories = get_the_category();
 if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[1]->name );   
} 
else $terms =  get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo $terms[1]->name;  

}
  if ( ! empty( $terms[1]->name ) ) {  
       echo $terms[0]->name; 
   }
                            ?>
```

so far is will show second, but not fall back to the first listed category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question clearly, you can achieve that with this code:

```php
<?php 
$terms =  get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    if (!empty($terms[0]->name))
        echo $terms[0]->name; // second category
    else 
        echo $terms[1]->name; // first (primary) category 
}
?>
```

Comment: YES! thank you, just had to switch the [0] and [1]s, but worked great. Thank you